# How to remove duplicate entries in list and merge non-duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `dict` like this:

```
seriesdict={'series':[],'id':[]}
```

where
`series` = the series name and
`id` = the unique id associated with the book in calibre

This `dict` is appended for each series to a list

```
sorted_data=[]
```

as this list will be used to request data from the internet, I'd like to reduce the amount of requests I have to do, both to safe time and reduce traffic on the site.
I'd like to check each series only once and move on to the next one.

I have already sorted the list according to the series, but I am struggling on how to check if the series is already in the list, and if so, how to add the following id's to the first added series.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
for entry in seriesdict:
    if entry['series'] not in sortedseriesdict['series']:
        sortedseriesdict['series']=entry['series']
        sortedseriesdict['ids']=entry['id']
        sorted_data.append(sortedseriesdict.copy())
    elif entry['series'] in sortedseriesdict['series']:
        sortedseriesdict['ids']=entry['id']
        sorted_data.append(sortedseriesdict.copy())
```

This [iteration question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740675/iterate-over-a-list-of-dictionary-and-update-values-from-previous-row) seems similar, but I am unsure if it could help in my case, as the ids being added have to keep all old data as well.

This is a part of the list:

```
[{'index': 237, 'series': '5 Centimeters per Second', 'id': '13050'}
{'index': 303, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '9809'},
{'index': 304, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '13540'},
{'index': 305, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '9289'},
{'index': 306, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '13323'},
{'index': 307, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '10783'},
{'index': 309, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '12084'},
{'index': 310, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '10943'},
{'index': 311, 'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '9202'},
{'index': 2329, 'series': 'A Certain Magical Index', 'id': '12843'}]
```

I would like to create the `seriesdict` so that the sorted_data looks like this:

```
[{'series': '5 Centimeters per Second', 'ids': '9809'},
 {'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'ids': '13540, 9289, 13323, 10783, 12084, 10943, 9202'},
 {'series': 'A Certain Magical Index', 'ids': '12843'},
 ...
]
```

How can I do that, if it is possible?
Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: What are the problems you seem to be facing? What is the expected output or the error code?

Comment: `for entry in seriesdict: ` iterates over dict keys (in your case `series` and `id`), they you try to subscript `series` key with `entry["series"]` so it actually looks like `series["series"]` during runtime. Assuming everything you have told up until here is correct, you should be encountering KeyError.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Can you provide a sample data set.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I'm currently not on my pc, ill update the question in ~40 minutes with the output I'm getting.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow, I've added a sample set and expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be dealing with series data, I would like to suggest using `pandas` library. This would save you a lot of hassle and tinkering around and will propose a solution with `pandas` first. First we will take your `seriesdict`and convert it to a `pandas.DataFrame` object.

```
import pandas as pd


series_dict = [
    {"index": 237, "series": "5 Centimeters per Second", "id": "13050"},
    {"index": 303, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "9809"},
    {"index": 304, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "13540"},
    {"index": 305, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "9289"},
    {"index": 306, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "13323"},
    {"index": 307, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "10783"},
    {"index": 309, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "12084"},
    {"index": 310, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "10943"},
    {"index": 311, "series": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "id": "9202"},
    {"index": 2329, "series": "A Certain Magical Index", "id": "12843"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(series_dict)
```

now `df` contains all the data we need and we can start modifying data as per your wish. For that we are going to group the data by `series` and take the `id` column of the result and apply a function that joins the column values with `,`. By resetting the index, we can achieve proper structure of the result dataframe.

```
df = df.groupby("series")["id"].apply(", ".join).reset_index()
```

Now if we print the result with :

```
print(df)
```

we get

```
                     series                                                 id
0  5 Centimeters per Second                                              13050
1             86 EIGHTY-SIX  9809, 13540, 9289, 13323, 10783, 12084, 10943,...
2   A Certain Magical Index                                              12843
```

If you really want to have the data in the structure you proposed,

```
my_data = [value for _, value in df.to_dict(orient="index").items()]
```

would return

```
[{'series': '5 Centimeters per Second', 'id': '13050'}, {'series': '86 EIGHTY-SIX', 'id': '9809, 13540, 9289, 13323, 10783, 12084, 10943, 9202'}, {'series': 'A Certain Magical Index', 'id': '12843'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tweaked the code a bit to create a csv file which will then be used further on to request data from the internet